# ForEach: ID parameter and closure return type

Tags: swiftui

So, I'm going through the SwiftUI documentation to get familiar. I was working on a grid sample app. It has the following code:

```
ForEach(allColors, id: \.description) { color in
    Button {
        selectedColor = color
    } label: {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4.0)
            .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: ContentMode.fit)
            .foregroundColor(color)
    }
    .buttonStyle(.plain)
}
```

It didn't occur to me first that ForEach is actually a struct, I thought it's a variation of the for in loop at first so I'm quite new at this. Then I checked the documentation.

When I read the documentation and some google articles for the ForEach struct, I didn't understand two points in the code:

- So we are initializing the foreach struct with an array of colors. For the the ID why did they use `.\description` instead of .self?
- Second is using `color in`. Since foreach is a struct and the paranthesis is the initializtion parameters this looks like the return type of a closure but why would we return individual colors to foreach? I thought the return is a collection of views or controls like button and label. This is like `var anInteger: Int = 1` for example. What type does ForEach accept as a result of the closure? Or am I reading this all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So we are initializing the foreach struct with an array of colors. For the the ID why did they use .\description instead of .self?

It depends on the type of `allColors`. What you should have in mind that `id` here is expected to be stable. The documentation states:

> It’s important that the id of a data element doesn’t change unless you replace the data element with a new data element that has a new identity. If the id of a data element changes, the content view generated from that data element loses any current state and animations.

So for example if colors are reference types (which are identifiable) and you swap one object with an identical one (in terms of field values), the identity *will* change, whereas `description` wouldn't (for the purposes of this example - just assuming intentions of code I have no access to).

**Edit:** Also note that in this specific example `allColors` appears to be a list of `Color`, which is *not* identifiable. So that's the reason behind the custom `id` keyPath.

Regarding your second point, note that the [trailing closure](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html) is *also* an initialization parameter. To see this clearly we could use the "non-sugared" version:

```
ForEach(allColors, id: \.description, content: { color in
    Button {
        selectedColor = color
    } label: {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4.0)
            .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: ContentMode.fit)
            .foregroundColor(color)
    }
    .buttonStyle(.plain)
})
```

where `content` is a closure (an anonymous function) that gets passed an element of the collection and returns some `View`.

So the idea is something like this: "Give me an collection of identifiable elements and I will call a function for each of these elements expecting from you to return me `some View`".

I hope that this makes (some) sense.

---

Additional remarks regarding some of the comments:

It appears to me that the main source of confusion is the closure itself. So let's try something else. Let's write the same code without a closure:

`ForEach`'s `init` has this signature:

```
init(_ data: Data, id: KeyPath<Data.Element, ID>, content: @escaping (Data.Element) -> Content)
```

Now, the `content` translates to:

*A function with one parameter of type `Data.Element`, which in our case is inferred from the `data` so it is a `Color`. The function's return type is `Content` which is a view builder that produces `some View`*

so our final code, which is equivalent to the first one, could look like this:

```
struct MyView: View {
    
    let allColors: [Color] = [.red, .green, .blue]
    @State private var selectedColor: Color?
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(allColors, id: \.description, content: colorView)
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func colorView(color: Color) -> some View {
        Button {
            selectedColor = color
        } label: {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4.0)
                .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: ContentMode.fit)
                .foregroundColor(color)
        }
        .buttonStyle(.plain)
    }
}
```

I hope that this could help to clarify things a little bit better.

Comment: So the closure is for content, not for ForEach. Ok. This is confusing a bit to me (to determine if the parameter is omitted due to memberwise initializer for ForEach or if its a trailing closure). The "colors in" is the giveaway I guess then. But, where is the return clause for the closure in this case? It is not a single line statement so to my understanding it is not an implicit return case. The documentation calls Content a view builder, it takes a data.element and returns content. Color is not a view though and there is no stack for views returned. I'm still a bit lost on this.

Comment: “The documentation calls Content a view builder, it takes a data.element and returns content”. Correct. In this case `Content` is the button inside the closure and the element is `color`.

Comment: Also, it might sound weird, but the code inside the closure (the Button) _is_ a single expression. Which means that it qualifies for implicit return (even if the function was not a viewBuilder). Btw implicit return (omit the return keyword) should not be confused with return type inference in closures.

Comment: Looking at the paratmeter definition it is "content: @escaping (Data.Element) -> Content". But we didn't pass a Data.Element into content since there are no paranthesis and the return type is listed as color because of "color in", not a view or control like button. Above you clarify that the element is color but its not in paranthesis and it preceds "in" so it looks like a return type. Assuming button is the implicit return I still don't understand the "color in" and lack of paranthesis with a variable in the initialization of content. If you could clarify that please.

Comment: @Process Please see my additional remarks.

Comment: Thank you for the remarks which I'm sure took a lot of time. So element for data.element for content initializiation was inferred from Data was an added understanding from the remarks. My remaining issue is that in your func version the func returns some view which makes sense but in the closure version the return type is color because of "{ color in". I understand how your version works. I don't understand how their version closure return type works. This was very educational, thank you.

Comment: I'm really glad that helped. I enjoy this so it's time well spent :P Regarding the `{ color in` no it's not the return type. The syntax is: `{ (<parameters>) -> <return type> in`. For example: in `[0, 1, 2].map { (i: Int) -> String in "\(i)" }` `i` is the parameter and `String` the return type.

Comment: oh... its lowercase, a type would be Uppercase so it can't be a return type making it a parameter for Content? sugar is bad, even in code :-(